# Apache delivering CSS and JS files, but browsers don't render them

Tags: apache-2.2, mime

A webpage is being hosted by apache2, CentOS 6.2.

It Gets HTML, CSS, JS files ok to the client side. But CSS and JS don't render, What can be hapenning?
Since they should run 100% on client side...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mime types are probably wrong.

Check they're serving the content with `Content-type: text/javascript` or `Content-type: text/css`. You can check this using the Network tab of Chrome's Inspector or Firebug.

You'll need [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype), and ensure you have these lines in your `httpd.conf`:

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```

That should do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right! most of them are 'Content-type: text/plain' Any tip on how to change them?

Comment: Please see my edits. You can also put those lines in a  `.htaccess` if you really have to, but will still need `mod_mime`.

Comment: It was enabled, added those lines. You are a Genius!

Comment: Nah, just someone who's had exactly the same problem in the past ;-) But thanks!